# Uploading and updating position anonymously on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So, what I want to do is for users to upload their positions to Firebase under a known key (so that the uploader can update his position), but anonymously.

When I use .push(), I do get a "unique" key, but I can't get the reference to update the position later.

If I use an uid, users are going to have access to other user's uids and I'm afraid this could be a security breach. (I'm not sure if uids are very relevant security-wise).

What can I do to post anonymous positions and update these fields later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication UID strings are not intended to be secure or private.  The only security is provided by [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) on the data you wish to protect.  If one user knows another user's UID, they don't know the identity of the person on the other side, unless you manage to leak that data by failing to protected it correctly with security rules.  So be sure to define what your access rules should be, and implement them accordingly.

If you want to use a push id for any reason, just be sure to store that unique string somewhere so you can use it later to construct a ref to the path where it was added.